# Log Scale on Reverse Cumulative Distribution Plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make ggplot2 use a logarithmic scale on the y axis for a reverse CDF?

This works:

```r
rnorm(64) %>%
  tibble(kbps = .) %>%
  ggplot() +
  stat_ecdf(aes(x = kbps, y = 1 - ..y..), pad=FALSE)
```

[image: works]

But this does not:

```r
rnorm(64) %>%
  tibble(kbps = .) %>%
  ggplot() +
  stat_ecdf(aes(x = kbps, y = 1 - ..y..), pad=FALSE) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

```
    
Warning: NaNs produced
Warning: [38;5;232mTransformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis[39m
Warning: [38;5;232mRemoved 64 rows containing missing values (`geom_step()`).[39m
```

[image: broken]

EDIT:

I want the outcome to look like this:

[image]

Image taken from: https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2018/7/229031-always-measure-one-level-deeper/fulltext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this. You could simply log manually and inverse transform the labels in `scale_y_continuous`

```r
rnorm(64) %>%
  tibble(kbps = .) %>%
  ggplot() +
  stat_ecdf(aes(x = kbps, y = log10(1 - after_stat(y))), pad = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous('1 - cdf (log scale)', breaks = seq(-3, 0), 
                     labels = 10^(seq(-3, 0)),
                     limits = c(-3, 0)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or precalculate 1 - ecdf and use `scale_y_log10` with `geom_step`

```r
tibble(kbps = rnorm(1000)) |> 
  arrange(kbps) |>
  mutate(ecdf = 1 - (row_number() - 1) / n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(kbps, ecdf)) +
  geom_step() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]